# Confusion about how define Rails associations for owners and members

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on defining a `User` class and a `Project` class. The `Project` has/belongs to an `:owner` (which is a `User`), and the `Project` has many `:team_members` (which are also `User`). A `User` can own many projects or be a `:team_member` on a project.

How do I define these associations on both of these classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could set it up like this:

```
user.rb
#id
has_many :projects, foreign_key: 'owner_id'
has_many :project_members, foreign_key: 'member_id' 


project.rb
#id
#owner_id
belongs_to :owner, class: 'User'
has_many :project_members


project_member.rb
#id
#member_id
#project_id
belongs_to :projects
belongs_to :member, class: 'User'
```

Comment: should it be project `has_one :project_team`?

Comment: In a sense, yes, but not in a database sense. You're using this table for a many to many relationship, recording the connections between projects and team members. Each record is a project_id and a member_id. That means for three members on a project, you have three records with the same project_id. So from the perspective of project.rb, it has many records in the project_team table.

Comment: I've changed the language from project_teams to project_members to help clarify.

Comment: Ah okay, making sense now...won't `project.find(id).project_members` return the `ProjectMember` records? How can we have it return the `User` records? What about something like `has_many :members, through: :project_members`?

Comment: You're on to something. I'd have to tool around with that (can't quite do it perfectly in my head yet) but there is definitely a solution there. You may need to explicitly declare the class and/or foreign key.